# Display and change ratings in iTunes Mini Player

Tags: itunes, music

Is there a way to display a song's ratings from the iTunes Mini Player? I know that I can right click in the display and view/change the ratings from there.

Can the ratings be added to the Mini Player view in some way? This would allow me to see the rating and check whether I have already rated that particular song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new iTunes 11 Mini Player has the option to view and change the ratings. In the Mini Player, hover over the player to show the controls instead of the title of the currently playing song. Then click the small arrow pointing to the right - not the forward control, but the one on the left of the player, next to the album artwork. It will open a menu, where the top entry is the current rating, allowing you to both view and change the rating. Exactly what I was looking for.

[image: Mini Player with Ratings]